# Extending Object Titles with Strings

Tags: java, string, extend

I have an object, of which I want the name to be randomized like this:

```
Object object = type_""+rand(1,4);
```

so "object" could be object_1, or object_2, etc. (they're defined somewhere else)
But this only seems to work if object is a String. How does it work for other types, too?

To make it more clear, here is an example, whcih creates a Sprite (in andengine):

```
super(2, 900, ResourcesManager.getInstance().box_1 , vbo);
```

But box_1 is randomized..could also be box_2, box_3...How can I achieve it?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Do you have your own class and want to set titles in it?  Do you want to construct objects of random types?

Comment: Your code does not compile, your question does not make sense

Comment: What do you mean with "Object titles"? There are no titles in Java. Please describe what do you really want to achieve/why this title is needed.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clear, so that we can help you

Comment: I want to refer to those already defined objects (object_1, object_2, etc.). I want to randomly "pick" one of them and use them later.

Comment: Sounds like you want to store a bunch of objects in an ArrayList. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: And use them for what? There is nothing else "in" that `Object` except the String "object_1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Completely rewritten based on the update to the question**

You can do this using Strings, but it's a bit hacky:

```
super(2, 900, ResourceManager.class.getDeclaredField("box_" + (1 + new Random().nextInt(2))).get(ResourcesManager.getInstance()) , vbo);
```

Comment: I think he is trying to select variables by name from the local scope. Which I guess would be possible in Python where everything is in a dict but not with Java.

Comment: @Maxaon3000 Yeah, he made an edit after I put my answer.  In java it's also possible although quite hacky.  You can get an object and get its property by the title of those properties.

Comment: You can get an object by it's property name using reflection but I think he is trying to select by variable name from the local scope.

Comment: Sorry for my bad word choise, what I really meant is how  can I randomize the values of an Object, like the last digit. If this is how I can do this, I really should consider redesigning the structure

Comment: Yeah redesign the structure and put them in a container and then select from the container.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to do it is impossible in Java. Your object references need to be in a container to select from them. For example you can use an array

```
Object[] arr= new Object[]{obj1,obj2,obj3};
Object rand = arr[new Random().nextInt(0,3)];
```